# Local embedded HTTP server that can respond to git commands?

Tags: java, git, http

I'm building a Git client in Java and would like to write automated tests that verify if Git commands running on an HTTP(s) server are running correctly. I've seen any number of local small Java HTTP servers, but it's unclear to me what would be involved in making them respond correctly to Git commands. I'm trying to avoid installing a local HTTP server because I'd like these automated tests to run anywhere. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

FYI, for ssh remote testing, I'm having fantastic success with the sshd mina system, and using its built-in GitPackCommandFactory. Something similar to HTTP(s) would be wonderful.

Comment: Have a look at Jgit, GitBlit and Jetty.

Answer (score 4):

The smart HTTP protocol of git is implemented in `git-http-backend`. This is a CGI binary that can be used in combination with some web-servers. Unfortunately it ignores the content-length of the request and relies on the server to close its input, which makes it incompatible with some CGI servers.

If you have python available, an easy way to run it would be using the CGIHTTPServer. This one is affected by the mentioned incompatibility. With a rather ugly workaround you can nevertheless make it work:

```
$ python -c 'import CGIHTTPServer; CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler.have_fork = False; CGIHTTPServer.test()' 8000
```

Or with python 3:

```
$ python3 -c 'import http.server; http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler.have_fork = False; http.server.test(HandlerClass=http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler, port=8000)'
```

These set the internal `have_fork` of `CGIHTTPRequestHandler` to `False` which causes the implementation to use subprocesses and pipes instead of fork to run the CGI binary. With this method, the incoming requests are buffered and written to a pipe, which is then closed. This fits the expected model of `git-http-backend` and therefore makes it work.

If you are on a system without fork in the first place (i.e. Windows) you don't need the workaround and can directly use:

```
$ python -m CGIHTTPServer 8000
$ python3 -m http.server --cgi 8000
```

Both setups require that `git-http-backend` is made available under a `cgi-bin` directory. The easiest setup is to create the cgi-bin directory inside a bare git repository, symlink or copy the `git-http-backend` binary into it and start the server from the bare repository:

```
$ git clone --bare <repo> bare.git
$ cd bare.git
$ touch git-daemon-export-ok
$ mkdir cgi-bin
$ ln -s /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend cgi-bin/git
$ python -c 'import CGIHTTPServer; CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler.have_fork = False; CGIHTTPServer.test()' 8000
```

With that setup, the repository is served at `http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/git` because `git-http-backend` was symlinked to `cgi-bin/git`. So the following should then work:

```
$ git clone http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/git clonedRepoName
```

To allow pushing into the bare repository use:

```
$ git config http.receivepack true
```

More advanced setups, with more than one repository served, can be made using the appropriate environment variables. Since the environment is inherited by the server and passed to the CGI binary, simply exporting the desired environment variables should work. See the [git-http-backend documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend) for all possible configuration and environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! Patched together a small server [(gist here)](https://gist.github.com/janakaud/09dc6fd8d37c62fed3e23819cce5e35d) that can serve a Git repo when launched within its root dir (no symlinking needed) - has CORS support for browser-originated access as well

Answer (score 0):

Based on Gustave's suggestion, I've discovered [SimpleHTTPServer](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.junit.http/src/org/eclipse/jgit/junit/http/SimpleHttpServer.java) within JGit. Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, I'm still fighting with paths and what not. This is pretty poorly documented. If someone's got a simpler solution, I'd still love to hear about it.